# GNU Parallel to run Python script on huge file

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing, gnu

I have a file which contains XML elements in every line, which needs to be converted to JSON. I have written a Python script which does the conversion but runs in serial mode. I have two options to use Hadoop or GNU Parallel, I have tried Hadoop and want to see how GNU could help, will be simple for sure.

My Python code is as follows:

`import sys
import json
import xmltodict
with open('/path/sample.xml') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        o=xmltodict.parse(line)
        t=json.dumps(o)
        with open('sample.json', 'a') as out:
            out.write(t+ "\n")`
So can I use GNU parallel to directly work on the huge file or do I need to split it?

Or is this right:
`cat sample.xml | parallel python xmltojson.py >sample.json`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your Python code to a UNIX filter, i.e. a program that reads from standard input (stdin) and writes to standard output (stdout). Untested:

```
import fileinput
import sys
import json
import xmltodict

for line in fileinput.input():
        o=xmltodict.parse(line)
        t=json.dumps(o)
        print t + "\n"
```

Then you use `--pipepart` in GNU Parallel:

```
parallel --pipepart -a sample.xml --block -1 python my_script.py
```

Comment: Gotta get you to 10k, Ole!

Comment: Ole, that cut down time from 59 min to 15 sec !!